# Returning array to main from a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, compression

So basically my problem is I want decompress function to sign output of "printf("%.*s", repeat, memset(set, c, repeat));" to array dest and return this dest to main and sign it to Decompressed_Message

here is an image of my problem

[image: here is image of my problem]

I want first decompressed version: and second one to be exactly same.
But however even I tried `sprintf()` I wasn't able to make it as I wish

here is my codes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
    
char* Compression(char* Message, int given_count)
{
    int Len;
    char count[given_count];
    int length = strlen(Message);
     
    char* destination = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (length * 2 + 1));
        
    int i;
    int j=0;
    int k;
     
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        destination[j++] = Message[i];
        Len = 1;
        while (i + 1 < length && Message[i] == Message[i + 1]) {
            Len++;
            i++;
        }
     
        sprintf(count, "%d", Len);
     
        for (k = 0; *(count + k); k++, j++) {
            destination[j] = count[k];
        }
    }
    destination[j] = '\0';
    return destination;
    free(destination);
}
    
char* Decompression(char *Compressed_Message, char* Message){
        
    int length = strlen(Message);
    char* dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (length * 2 + 1));
        
    while(*Compressed_Message){
        int repeat = 0;
        char c = *Compressed_Message++;   
        while(isdigit(*Compressed_Message))
        {
            repeat = repeat*10 + *Compressed_Message++ - '0'; 
        }
        char set[repeat];
        printf("%.*s", repeat, memset(set, c, repeat)); 
        memset(dest, c, repeat);
    }
        
    dest[length] = '\0';
    return dest;
    free(dest);
}
        
int main(void) {
    
    int letters;
    float compression_odd;
    
    printf("Data compressor and decompressor\n\n");
        
    FILE *file;
    char filename[100]="";  
    printf("\n\nPlease Enter the name of file: ");
    scanf("%99s",filename);
    file=fopen(filename,"r");
    if(file==NULL){
        printf("\n%s File not found.\n\n",filename);
        exit(1);
    }
        
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long count = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        
    char Message[count];
        
    fread(Message, strlen(Message)+1, count, file);  
    Message[count]='\0';
        
    printf("\nMessage: %s\n", Message);
        
    printf("char number of message: %d\n", strlen(Message));
    printf("\nCompressed version: ");
    char* Compressed_Message = Compression(Message, count);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", Compressed_Message);
    printf("\nchar number of compressed message: %d\n", strlen(Compressed_Message));
    compression_odd = ((strlen(Message) - strlen(Compressed_Message)) * 100) / strlen(Message);
        
    if (compression_odd > 100 || compression_odd < 0){
        printf("\nCompression ratio is negative Message got longer !\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nCompression Ratio is approximately: %.2f", compression_odd);
    }
    
    printf("\nDecompressed version: ");
    char* Decompressed_Message = Decompression(Compressed_Message, Message);
        
    printf("\nDecompressed version: %s", Decompressed_Message);
        
    /*if (strcmp(Message, DecompressedSize) == 0) {
      printf("\nCompression done.\n");
      } else {
      printf("\nCompression crushed!\n");
      }*/
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI: Neither of your `free()` calls will be executed, since the function stops at `return`.

Comment: It's lucky that doesn't get executed, because then the caller wouldn't be able to use the array you're returning.

Comment: `fread(Message, strlen(Message)+1, count, file);` should be `fread(Message, 1, count, file);` `Message` hasn't been initialized, so you can't get its length. You want to read `count` bytes.

Comment: But that won't cause a problem, because there are only `count` bytes that can be read.

Comment: It will be much easier for you (and us) if you do not use any file functions only arrays with data and we will be able to reproduce it. All scanf fopen etc in questions not related to the file systems should not be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your `Decompression()` function.

```
char* dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (length * 2 + 1));
```

That doesn't allocate a big enough destination. For instance, if the compressed string is `a100`, the destination needs to be at least 101 characters, but you'll only allocate 9 characters. There's no way to know how big the destination needs to be without reading all the repetition counts; you should grow the destination incrementally using `realloc()`.

In the `while` loop, you keep copying each repeated character to `dest`, rather than copying it after the previous block. So at the end, it just contains the last repeated character, not all of them.

You don't need the `set` array. You can use `memset()` directly into `dest` (after adding the adjustment to append to the previous block) and print that the way you were printing `set`.

```
char* Decompression(char *Compressed_Message, char* Message){
        
    int length = 0;
    char* dest = NULL;
        
    while(*Compressed_Message){
        int repeat = 0;
        char c = *Compressed_Message++;   
        while(isdigit(*Compressed_Message))
        {
            repeat = repeat*10 + *Compressed_Message++ - '0'; 
        }
        dest = realloc(dest, length + repeat + 1);
        printf("%.*s", repeat, memset(dest + length, c, repeat)); 
        length += repeat;
    }
        
    dest[length] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: you are truely great thanks for all these explanations. also I just realized how brutally I did that free mistakes after returns... further more I wanna ask something my malloc takes memory in heap for function of Compression , shouldn't I make it free somewhere ? 
maybe in int main() with free(Compressed_Message) ?

Comment: Yes, you should free both `Compressed_Message` and `Decompressed_Message` in `main()` after you print all the results.

Comment: yes I did like that, thank you so much again